# Why my pickerview doesn't appear on certain text field?

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uipickerview

I have found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_u6CqM1m-EA) where was shown way for adding picker views with fields to the app. I have added three fields:

```
@IBOutlet weak var position: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var emplFilter: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var locFilter: UITextField!
```

and also variables which represents current text field and picker:

```
var currentTextField = UITextField()
var currentPicker = UIPickerView()
```

and also added implementations:

```
UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,UITextFieldDelegate,UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource
```

Added all methods:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if currentTextField == locFilter{
            return location.count
        }else if currentTextField == test{
            return proffestion.count
        }else if currentTextField == emplFilter{
            return employer.count
        }else{
            return 0
        }
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if currentTextField == locFilter{
            return location[row].name
        }else if currentTextField == test{
            return proffestion[row].name
        }else if currentTextField == emplFilter{
            return employer[row].name
        }else{
            return ""
        }
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if currentTextField == locFilter{
            
            locFilter.text = location[row].name
            filters!["location"] = location[row].id
            self.view.endEditing(true)
            
        }else if currentTextField == test{
            
            filters!["prof"] = proffestion[row].id
            test.text =  proffestion[row].name
            self.view.endEditing(true)
            
        }else if currentTextField == emplFilter{
            
            emplFilter.text = employer[row].name
            filters!["employer"] = "\(String(describing: employer[row].id))"
            self.view.endEditing(true)
        }
    }
    
    
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        self.currentPicker.delegate = self
        self.currentPicker.dataSource = self
        
        print("click")
        
        
        currentTextField = textField
        
        
        if currentTextField == locFilter{
            currentTextField.inputView = currentPicker
        }else if currentTextField == test{
           currentTextField.inputView = currentPicker
        }else if currentTextField == emplFilter{
           currentTextField.inputView = currentPicker
        }
        
        self.currentPicker.delegate = self
        self.currentPicker.dataSource = self
    }
```

and here I have a problem - when I click on `position` field I don't see any output in logs. I can't understand why it happens, I tried to add another field but it didn't change the situation. I tried to use another array but I also didn't see any picker view. I tried to look for any possible solution in the Internet, but I didn't succeed in it :(

Comment: Where are setting the textfield delegates?

Comment: at storyboard like in video

Comment: @Frankenstein, thank you so much :) I didn't set delegate for this field :)

Comment: @Frankenstein, if you want you can post an answer which I will apply. I'm new in iOS development that is why I did this mistake :(

Comment: It's ok. Even experienced devs make this mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `delegate` of `position` `UITextField` should fix the issue.

```
position.delegate = self
```

I would also like to point out that you don't need to repetitively set `delegate` and `dataSource` of `UIPickerView` everytime a text field begins editing.

Comment: You're welcome. You could move the `currentPicker.delegate = self` to `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: but in video this delegate was in func of field selection, is it wrong?